# R freezes and my computer too

Tags: r

I don't know whether my question is an easy one to answer, but let's ask it. I'm using R for corpus linguistics and I want to make concordance with a regular expression, using "exact.matches" (cf. St. Th. Gries). The problem is that when I let R run the script, it freezes a long time and my computer freezes too. So I have to restart everything with the power button of my computer.

What I want to try to analyse is a collection of 100 texts (in txt format). The whole bundle is 17,254,537 tokens big, but I have tried to run the code for 20 files at a time. Same problem: everything freezes. Here comes the code:

```
rm(list=ls(all=T))

setwd("C:/Users/Christophe/Documents/Doctorat_ULg/Corpora/Dutch/Gutenberg_corpus_NL")
source("C:/_qclwr/_scripts/_scripts_code-exerciseboxes_chapters_3-5/exact_matches_new.R")

corpus.files.1<-choose.files() # to load the first 58 text files
corpus.files.2<-choose.files() # to load the 42 other files
whole.corpus.file<-c(corpus.files.1, corpus.files.2) # to concatenate everything into one vector
all.matches.verbs<-vector()    

for(i in whole.corpus.files) {
  current.corpus.file<-scan(i, what="char", sep="\n", quiet=T)
  current.matches.verbs<-exact.matches("aan<prep>", current.corpus.file, case.sens=F, pcre=T)
  if(length(current.matches.verbs)==0) { next }
  all.matches.verbs<-append(all.matches.verbs, current.matches.verbs)
}
```

Is there an easy way to solve this problem? It seems it is a problem of memory. I typed the following, if it can help:

```
> memory.size()
[1] 35.02
> memory.limit()
[1] 3976
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger (Mb) max used (Mb)
Ncells  558406 29.9     818163 43.7   741108 39.6
Vcells 1039743  8.0    1757946 13.5  1300290 10.0
```

I thank you in advance for your precious help.

Best,

CBechet.

Comment: Classic mistake: You are growing an object in a loop. Read the Second Circle of the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: Predefine the size of an object before going into the loop

Comment: If I cheat a little bit and try to use an external hard-drive (1TB), even though it wouldn't solve the problem of growing objects, do you think it could work?

Comment: Don't grow an object in a loop. Period.

Comment: @Alexey Ferapontov, a clumsy question: how to predefine the size of an object?

Comment: If you know the max size of a data frame, you can use methods such as `matrix(nrow = blah)` or `as.character(length=blah)` or smth along the lines, so you do not dynamically change the length of an object in a loop

Comment: The thing is that I'm not using any data frame here, and most of the examples that are provided to illustrate why loops should not be used are examples with data frames, which is a pity. Should I try something with a function from the apply-family?

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to the for-loop:

```
rm(list=ls(all=T))

setwd("C:/Users/Christophe/Documents/Doctorat_ULg/Corpora/Dutch/Gutenberg_corpus_NL")
source("C:/_qclwr/_scripts/_scripts_code-exerciseboxes_chapters_3-5/exact_matches_new.R")

corpus.files.1<-choose.files() # loads the first set of corpus files
corpus.files.2<-choose.files() # loads the second set of corpus files
whole.corpus.file<-c(corpus.files.1, corpus.files.2) # concatenate all the corpus files into one vector

whole.text <-unlist(lapply(whole.corpus.file, function(x) scan(x, what="char", sep="\n", quiet=T))) # reads the content of the files in the vector
```

And the data is still too big (and I'm not using a for-loop):

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4.3 Mb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In substr(lines, if (characters.around != 0) starts - characters.around else 1,  :
  Reached total allocation of 3976Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In substr(lines, if (characters.around != 0) starts - characters.around else 1,  :
  Reached total allocation of 3976Mb: see help(memory.size)
3: In substr(lines, if (characters.around != 0) starts - characters.around else 1,  :
  Reached total allocation of 3976Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In substr(lines, if (characters.around != 0) starts - characters.around else 1,  :
  Reached total allocation of 3976Mb: see help(memory.size)
```